# How to filter Google Play so app only displays to 7in tablets

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, filtering, release

I recently released an app that only supports 7-8.9inch screens (600dp width).
I thought I had applied the correct tag within the manifest to tell Google play to filter out other devices.

In the AndroidManifest.xml I used:

supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
android:largestWidthLimitDp="600"

**however** it turns out google play doesn't filter with the tag "requiresSmallestWidthDp"
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

(despite using it here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)

How can I filter the app so that the play store will only display the app to compatible (7 - 8.9 in devices. Or only 7in devices as a worst case) devices?

I looked into using compatible-screens but came to the conslusion these are too broad and that a 7in and 10in device would come under the same bracket of large screenSize, which would be useless for me.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following manifest should do the trick:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" /> <!-- may not need this one-->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

It seems that the `requiresSmallestWidthDp` will be supported in the future for filtering apps on Google Play but not currently:

> Caution: The Android system does not pay attention to this attribute, so it does not affect how your application behaves at runtime. Instead, it is used to enable filtering for your application on services such as Google Play. However, Google Play currently does not support this attribute for filtering (on Android 3.2), so you should continue using the other size attributes if your application does not support small screens.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: Almost perfect, A few devices I don't want on there but they're easy to pick off with the development console, thank